# sdk manager cant create android virtual device

Tags: android, sdk, virtual-device-manager

I have installed the latest Android SDK today and have installed and updated all available packages. I now need to see if I can create an android virtual device before I can go on further. I followed this procedure from the Android SDK and AVD manager:

1. click on Virtual devices
2. click "new" button and type in "Honeycomb" in the name field
3. For target, I choose "Android 3.0 API 11"
4. When trying to start the virtual device the emulator tries to load but i just get:

> emulator: ERROR: unknown virtual device name: 'honeycomb'
>   emulator: could not find virtual device named 'honeycomb'

If it makes a difference the SDK manager is installed on the C/ drive and the .android folder is on the D/ drive.

I'm running Windows 7. I've tried turning off antivirus to see if that is the issue.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

PS it is installed in c/ program files
 and the target output is d/.android if i am not mistaken ==ill try and reinstall the sdk to the d drive and see what happens.
thanks for all helpful comments

pps: I also have an xp computer-would it be any easier to isntall to xp?

Comment: What's the output of "android list target" at the command line?

Comment: Where in the C-drive have you installed it to? `Program files`? If so, I've heard of people having problems with that as the `Program files`-folders in Windows 7 are somewhat restricted (need Admin permission to make changes. It still occurs if you are Admin on your computer). If that is the case, I would suggest moving the SDK-folder to another location and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think this answer might be too late for you, but others can be benefited by it,
when you click on your AVD Manager you will get a window with 2 options 
1)Android Virtual Devices 
2)Device Definition

Select the device definition and select any one of the nexus configurations and on the right side panel select the create new AVD option it should work